# Adobe Javascript Changing 30 day calendar (Includes 30 Day Code With Image) to 30 Days, 14 days or 7 days Depending Selection

Tags: javascript, date, adobe

This Is The Code Im Using For A 30 Day Calander:

```
var s1 = this.getField("Date").valueAsString;
if (s1=="") event.value = "";
else {
    var d1 = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", s1);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate()+30);
    event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", d1);
}
```

The Goal Is To Make It 14 days If 2.17 Is Selected and 7 days if 4.33 Only If Necessary, String Could Be Used As indicator, example:

```
var P = Number(this.getField("PaymentFrequency").valueAsString);
```

// Select 7 Days / Select 14 Days Or Select 30 Days Etc.
//  weekly, Bi-Weekly, or Monthly If Name Of Frequency Is Selected.

See Image Below For Visual:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I Had To Geuss How This Would Look Like, Keep In Mind I Have Limited Knowledge In Coding, Would Really Appreciate The Help!

```
var P = Number(this.getField("PaymentFrequency").valueAsString);

var s1 = this.getField("Date").valueAsString;
if (s1=="") event.value = "";
If var P == Monthly;
    var d1 = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", s1);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate()+30);
    event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", d1);
}else{
var s1 = this.getField("Date").valueAsString;
if (s1=="") event.value = "";
else {
if var P == Bi-Weekly
    var d1 = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", s1);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate()+14);
    event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", d1);
}else{
var s1 = this.getField("Date").valueAsString;
if (s1=="") event.value = "";
else {
If var P == Weekly;
    var d1 = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", s1);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate()+7);
    event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", d1);
```